# splitting an equation inside curly brackets onto 2 lines without using \Big

Tags: equations

I have a long equation:

```
\begin{equation} \begin{split}
X_{t} = mean(\left\{|Y_{t-4} - Z_{t-4}|,...,\\
                    |Y_{t+4} - Z_{t+4}|\right\})
\end{equation} \begin{split}
```

that I want to split over 2 lines and align as shown, but because it uses set notation and has small normal brackets outside the curly brackets, I don't want to use big curly brackets with the \bigg command when split over 2 lines. The \split command prevents me from using \left\ { and \right\ } with a line split. Is there a way of forcing small curly brackets with the split line command?

**How I solved the problem:**

This can be achieved by use of pseudo-parentheses:

```
 \begin{equation} \begin{split}
 X_{t} = mean(\left\{&|Y_{t-4} - Z_{t-4}|,...,\right\.\\
                    &\left\.|Y_{t+4} - Z_{t+4}|\right\})
 \end{equation} \end{split}
```

or better still as @Werner suggested, without the use of \right or \left:

```
\begin{equation} \begin{split}
X_{t} = mean(\{&|Y_{t-4} - Z_{t-4}|,...,\\
               &|Y_{t+4} - Z_{t+4}|\})
\end{equation} \end{split}
```

I used the second option as it was simpler.

Comment: Yes there is. Just use `\{` and `\}`. No need for `\left` and `\right` here.

Comment: @Werner - I don't have enough reputation points to upvote yet, but thanks for the answer!
Also, just found a quick solution with \left and \right. You can terminate with pseudo-parenthesis \left\. and \right\.

Comment: @user2524828 I don't think you should use `\left` and `\right` here, since this could lead to curly braces of different sizes.  To illustrate try: 
`\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left\{ a \right. & \\ & \left. \sum_{n=0}^{3} \right\} 
\end{split}
\end{equation}`

Comment: @MorganSherman - thanks for the tip. I discovered this yesterday when trying out the two options in my document, and decided to go with the \{ and \} options as you suggest.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need `\left` and `\right`; your input has several mistakes, by the way: for instance `\split{equation}` means nothing (and it will produce errors). Also “mean” should be treated as an operator. I don't think the parentheses `()` around the set are useful.

With `split` you can choose the alignment point; here's a possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
  X_{t} = \operatorname{mean}(\{\,
    &\lvert Y_{t-4} - Z_{t-4}\rvert,\dots,\\
    &\lvert Y_{t+4} - Z_{t+4}\rvert\,\})
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry that was a transcription error : I have used \begin{split} and \end{split}. Corrected in the question. Thanks for the tip re mean